# How to convert object return by laravel model factory create method into array containing model fields?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6.2, laravel-factory

For example, I have a `UserFactory.php`

```php
<?php

use App\User;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'role' => 'USER',
        'password' => 'sasdcsdf34', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

Now, I can create a user as following

```php
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
```

Now, How can I convert this `$user` object into array containing user info like name,email etc without initializing new array and manually assigning every `$user` object property. ??

I DON'T want to manually assign like following as it is tedious if there are many properties in `$user` object

```php
       $userArray=[     
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email 
             ]
```

I have tried this but it creates array containing various other properties and actual values needed are nested inside properties

```php
$userArray=array($user)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try using the raw method of factory instead of create.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->raw();
```

This should give you an array you can work with.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add something like this to your model class:

```
public function getArr(){
        foreach($this->attributes as $key => $val){
            $array[$key] = $val;
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

If you wish to have this function in every model you could create trait with this function and then just attach it in model class or any class extending it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is this the best approach and is it efficient to use loop? I mean aren't there any magic methods in `User` model or any laravel's helper function ?

Comment: Well, you are right. You can just return `$this->attributes` in function which gives the same effect.

Comment: Does this work? I  had previously  checked using`dd($user)` . I may have not seen atrributes property. I couldn't try now . I will check it out soon.

Comment: Atrributes property is protected which means that you can not access them outside of the class, therefore you need to make public function which can get them for you.

Comment: ok. so  can I convert it to array just like `array($user->attributes)`  ??

Comment: No. If you add above function to your model class, then you can do `$array = $user->getArr();`

Comment: So, you mean i can return attributes using `return (array($this->attributes))` ? If not please show its implementation?

Comment: Your model class file `User.php`:
`<?php
namespace App;
...
public function getArr(){
    return $this->attributes;
}
?>`

Your file where you wish to get model's attributes and their values:
`<?php
user App\User;
...
$user = User::find($user_id);
$array = $user->getArr():
?>`

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 8, instead of make or create method, use:

```
User::factory()->raw();
```

This will return an array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode`.

```
// Laravel 7
$userArray = json_decode(factory(User::class)->create(), true);

// Laravel 8
$userArray = json_decode(User::factory()->create(), true);
```